# is is possible to have multiple layouts in Gatsby

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I am looking to have a layout for my home page, resume pages, blog pages, and other pages.

So far in the tutorial, all I see is this:

```js
import React from "react";

export default ({ children }) => (
  <div style={{ margin: `0 auto`, maxWidth: 650, padding: `0 1rem` }}>
    {children()}
  </div>
);
```

This does not allow me to specify which page this applies to.  It seems to apply to all child pages

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `gatsby-node.js`:

```
// Implement the Gatsby API “onCreatePage”. This is
// called after every page is created.
exports.onCreatePage = async ({ page, boundActionCreators }) => {
  const { createPage } = boundActionCreators;

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (page.path.match(/^\/landing-page/)) {
      // It's assumed that `landingPage.js` exists in the `/layouts/` directory
      page.layout = "landingPage";

      // Update the page.
      createPage(page);
    }

    resolve();
  });
};
```

Create `src/layouts/landingPage.js`. This will be the new layout template.

Create `src/pages/landing-page/index.js`. This will be the index page for the newly created layout template.

Source: [Creating and modifying pages | GatsbyJS](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/creating-and-modifying-pages/#choosing-the-page-layout)

Comment: Careful! Using this verbatim causes Gatsby v2 to go into an infinite loop and fail to build.